# Unable to load the 'nvidia-drm' kernel module

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kernel, nvidia, manjaro

I'm trying to install nvidia drivers on my Manjaro linux. But .run file tells me "ERROR: Unable to load the 'nvidia-drm' kernel module." What should i do?